# Retrieving elements with custom HTML attributes

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I have the following website: https://www.kvk.nl/handelsregister/publicaties/, where I would like to retrieve the login link with Selenium, Scrapy and Python. So for the relevant function, I have the following code:

```
def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Drivers", "chromedriver.exe"))
        self.driver.get(self.initial_url)
        test = access_page_wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[data-ui-test-class="linkCard_toegangscode"]')))
    if test.is_displayed():
        print("+1")
    else:
        print("-1")
```

However, this does not seem to work, since it just waits 15 seconds and then it stops. It will never reach +1 or -1.

Now my question is, how can we point selenium to the correct element. It also does not seem to work using XPATH `find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-ui-test-class='linkCard_toegangscode']")`.

Should I use another selection approach and if yes, which one?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium to mix Scrapy and Selenium, to prevent other issues you might run into in the future.

Comment: I actually only want Selenium to log me in and get the page behind the authentication. Pass the login authentication headers /session to my Scrapy spider and then I continue to scrape. I believe that Scrapy is a bit faster since it doesn't require a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is Frame which stopping you to access the element.Switch_To iframe and then access the element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import os
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Drivers", "chromedriver.exe"))
driver.get("https://www.kvk.nl/handelsregister/publicaties/")
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
test=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[data-ui-test-class="linkCard_toegangscode"]')))
if test.is_displayed():
    print("+1")
else:
    print("-1")
```

Try the above code.It should print what you are looking after.